# return a value after Activity.runOnUiThread() method

Tags: android, interface, runnable

Is it possible to return a value after `Activity.runOnUiThread()` method.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int var = SOMETHING;

        // how to return var value.         
    }
});
```

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684468/java-runnable-run-method-returning-a-value) i see that it's not possible to return a value after `Runnable.run()` method. But how to use (implement) another interface and return a value after execution.

Hope it's clear for all.

**EDIT**

May help someone else.

I useD @Zapl's solution, and passED a parameter inside the `Callable` class constructor, like this :

```
class MyCallable implements Callable<MyObject> {

        int param;

        public MyCallable (int param) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.param = param;
        }

        @Override
        public MyObject call() throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return methodReturningMyObject(this.param);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you really want to do it you can use futures and `Callable` which is roughly a `Runnable` but with return value.

```
    final String param1 = "foobar";

    FutureTask<Integer> futureResult = new FutureTask<Integer>(new Callable<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer call() throws Exception {
            int var = param1.hashCode();
            return var;
        }
    });


    runOnUiThread(futureResult);
    // this block until the result is calculated!
    int returnValue = futureResult.get();
```

This also works for exceptions thrown inside `call`, they will be re-thrown from `get()` and you can handle them in the calling thread via

```
    try {
        int returnValue = futureResult.get();
    } catch (ExecutionException wrappedException) {
        Throwable cause = wrappedException.getCause();
        Log.e("Error", "Call has thrown an exception", cause);
    }
```

Comment: I needed to pass a parameter in the callable method. I have update the question. Thanks so much

Comment: @mansoulx if you rename `int position;` to `int param` you should have a working solution. Otherwise just use a `final` local variable as parameter. Edit: added final var example to answer.

Comment: `int param` is the variable i used to iterate over a for loop. I don't think a `final` declaration will fit well ... ?!

Comment: I don't understand. But `MyCallable` declares that it has a field `position` that is nowhere used and you do `this.param = param;` although there is no field named `param` (e.g. `private int param;` - can be final since nothing is changing that after construction).

Comment: @mansoulx I'm confused now :) Did you solve your problem using `MyCallable` or is that a question? `final` in a for loop would work like http://pastebin.com/5wGZyTzQ btw

Comment: Yes it's ok now :). ok your declare new `final index` to take `i` value, ok thank you again.

Comment: @zapl `// this block until the result is calculated!` how will it block? the function will wait for UI to complete then continue the code followed?

Comment: @Fei  yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem there is that you need to handle `final` variables to be passed to the `runOnUiThread()` method, and that implies that you cannot modify them inside. However, there is a trick, you can declare a non-primitive data structure prior to the `runOnUiThread()`, for example a `String[]` in the case you want to return a `String`. Of course, you'll need to declare it as `final`

Once done, in the `runOnUiThread()` method simply assign the return value you want in `yourarray[0]`, so after you'll be able to access it once you're out the method.

**---- EDIT ----**

Example:

```
private void my_method() {
  final String[] your_array = new String[1];

  ...

  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int var = SOMETHING;

        your_array[0] = "Hello!!!";

        // how to return var value.         
    }
  });

  System.out.println("I've got a message! It says... " + your_array[0]);
}
```

Comment: thanks for replying. what do you mean by `access it once you're out the method.` : does it mean I can access it just after runOnUiThread instruction ?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example of what I mean, I hope that's what you've been looking for.

Comment: That is not guaranteed to work since the thread writing to `your_array[0]` is not guaranteed to be done at that point. You have to wait. And it will in practice pretty much never work.

Comment: Correct. This could be combined with a CountDownLatch(1) to synchronize both events (assignation and access). A good example is in the Android reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html

Comment: That *might* still be unsafe unless you add some `volatile` or [in case of arrays](http://jeremymanson.blogspot.de/2009/06/volatile-arrays-in-java.html) use e.g. `AtomicIntegerArray`. Not sure if `CountDownLatch` establishes a proper `happens-before` relation. My guess is no.

Comment: From the reference I understand that using CountDownLatch(1) is intended exactly for this, however, I agree with the rest of your comment.

Comment: Ok I think my guess is wrong and you don't need volatile on top " actions in a thread prior to calling countDown() happen-before actions following a successful return from a corresponding await() in another thread." from the docs.

Comment: grazie molte. Un trucco tanto semplice quanto efficace. Grazie.

Answer (score 1):

you can use handler to send message back.

check following example
[Android: When should I use a Handler() and when should I use a Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954611/android-when-should-i-use-a-handler-and-when-should-i-use-a-thread)